# Регулярное выражение php, как составить такое регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать такое регулярное выражение, например дается строчка

`<0>SS</0><1>DD</1><m>65</m>`

Требуется найти первое имя тега тоесть `0`, между тегами любое имя, и если найден закрывающий тег, значит все верно, выдать `0`

Примеры, даются строчки

`<0>ЛЮБОЙ ТЕКСТ</0>` должен выдать `0`

`<0>ЛЮБОЙ ТЕ<0>ЛЮБОЙ ТЕКСТ` ничего не должен вывести потамучто нету `</0>`

`<ms>SS<1>DD</1>` должен выдать 1

`<0>SS</0><1>DD</1>` должен выдать только 0

`<ms>SS</ms><1>DD</1>` должен выдать ms

`<0>ЛЮБОЙ ТЕ<1>ЛЮБОЙ ТЕКСТ</0>` выдать 0

Вот такое думаю не сложное регулярное выражение требуется сделать, надо написать только регулярное выражение ,а не php код...

Comment: А если будет строка `<0>ЛЮБОЙ ТЕ<1>ЛЮБОЙ ТЕКСТ</0>`, то что должно вернутся?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регулярное выражение: `/<(.+?)>.*<\/\1>/`

https://regex101.com/r/aL4lR2/1